# ARRAY_AGG interrupted by GROUP BY when trying to ORDER BY timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-json, array-agg

I have prepared an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2c9c5/49) for my problem -

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE chat(
    gid integer,            /* game id */
    uid integer,            /* user id */
    created timestamptz,
    msg text
);
```

filled with the following test data:

```
INSERT INTO chat(gid, uid, created, msg) VALUES
    (10, 1, NOW() + interval '1 min', 'msg 1'),
    (10, 2, NOW() + interval '2 min', 'msg 2'),
    (10, 1, NOW() + interval '3 min', 'msg 3'),
    (10, 2, NOW() + interval '4 min', 'msg 4'),
    (10, 1, NOW() + interval '5 min', 'msg 5'),
    (10, 2, NOW() + interval '6 min', 'msg 6'),
    (20, 3, NOW() + interval '7 min', 'msg 7'),
    (20, 4, NOW() + interval '8 min', 'msg 8'),
    (20, 4, NOW() + interval '9 min', 'msg 9');
```

I can use the following query:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(
          gid, array_to_json(y)
       ) FROM (
       SELECT  gid,
          array_agg(
            json_build_object(
              'uid', uid,
              'created', EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM created)::int,
              'msg', msg)
          ) y
        FROM  chat 
        GROUP BY gid /*, created
        ORDER BY created ASC */
) x;
```

for fetching the table records as a JSON object with "gid" as keys and array-values:

```
{ "20" : [
    {"uid" : 3, "created" : 1514889490, "msg" : "msg 7"},
    {"uid" : 4, "created" : 1514889550, "msg" : "msg 8"},
    {"uid" : 4, "created" : 1514889610, "msg" : "msg 9"}
], 

"10" : [
    {"uid" : 1, "created" : 1514889130, "msg" : "msg 1"},
    {"uid" : 2, "created" : 1514889190, "msg" : "msg 2"},
    {"uid" : 1, "created" : 1514889250, "msg" : "msg 3"},
    {"uid" : 2, "created" : 1514889310, "msg" : "msg 4"},
    {"uid" : 1, "created" : 1514889370, "msg" : "msg 5"},
    {"uid" : 2, "created" : 1514889430, "msg" : "msg 6"}
] }
```

However I am missing a minor thing and just can't figure it out:

I need to order the arrays by "created".

So I add `ORDER BY created ASC` to the above query and also have to add `GROUP BY gid, created` (you can see the problematic code as commented out in the above query).

This *breaks* however the `array_agg` and results in 1-element arrays (and overwrites duplicated "gid" keys, when returned as `jsonb` from my custom stored function):

```
{ "10": [{ "uid":2, "created":1514889800, "msg":"msg 6" }],

  "20": [{ "uid":4, "created":1514889980, "msg":"msg 9" }] }
```

Is ordering even possible here or should I resort to doing it in my JAVA application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the `ORDER BY` in the `array_agg` call:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(gid, array_to_json(y))
FROM (
  SELECT  gid,
    array_agg(
      json_build_object(
        'uid', uid,
        'created', EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM created)::int,
        'msg', msg
      ) ORDER BY created -- Order the elements in the resulting array
    ) AS y
  FROM chat 
  GROUP BY gid
) x;
```

returns (formatted using `jq`):

```
{
  "10": [
    {
      "uid": 1,
      "created": 1514890093,
      "msg": "msg 1"
    },
    {
      "uid": 2,
      "created": 1514890153,
      "msg": "msg 2"
    },
    {
      "uid": 1,
      "created": 1514890213,
      "msg": "msg 3"
    },
    {
      "uid": 2,
      "created": 1514890273,
      "msg": "msg 4"
    },
    {
      "uid": 1,
      "created": 1514890333,
      "msg": "msg 5"
    },
    {
      "uid": 2,
      "created": 1514890393,
      "msg": "msg 6"
    }
  ],
  "20": [
    {
      "uid": 3,
      "created": 1514890453,
      "msg": "msg 7"
    },
    {
      "uid": 4,
      "created": 1514890513,
      "msg": "msg 8"
    },
    {
      "uid": 4,
      "created": 1514890573,
      "msg": "msg 9"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that [ORDER BY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html) can be used with aggregate functions, thank you!